# Получаю ответ от сервера, но не могу открыть другую активность

Tags: java, android

Мутный заголовок получился. Ну, да ладно.
Проблема, собственно, такая: развернул локальный сервер, на котором одна переменная с плавающим значением (0/1). При получении 1 мне надо открыть другую активность.
Значения я получаю. Для наглядности даже выводится в TextView и в Log. Но не могу понять как при этом ответе перейти на другую активность.

```
response = task.execute(url).get(); //тут получил ответ 0 или 1
```

далее пробую:

```
if (response.equals("1")) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

И ничего не происходит. Пробовал compareTo и тоже не происходит ничего. Алярма
Полный код:

```
private void getResponse() {
    DownloadAnswerServerTask task = new DownloadAnswerServerTask();
    try {
        response = task.execute(url).get();
        Log.i("MyResponse", response);
        if(response.equals("1")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class DownloadAnswerServerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(strings[0]).openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(250);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(250);
            if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == urlConnection.getResponseCode()) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) builder.append(line).append("\n");
                return builder.toString();
            } else {
                Log.i("MyError", getString(R.string.response_server));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас int или стринг response?

Comment: String response

Comment: Пройдитесь дебагом и убедитесь, что условие `if (response.equals("1"))` выполняется и код внутри условия тоже.

Comment: Действительно, прошелся дебагером и он показал, что значение response = null. Но в лог выводится все правильно. Ответ с сервака получаю

Comment: Видимо, в коде эти два фрагмента стоят не друг под другом... Можете обновить вопрос и показать в нём чуть больше кода? (( `task` - это экземпляр класса `AsyncTask`? ))

Comment: Да, AsyncTask) все правильно заметили

Comment: По моему мнению, пропущена строка `urlConnection.connect();` перед сравнением кода ответа (`getResponseCode()`)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо большое за ответ. Нашел причину. Я зря решил в билдер перенос строки добавить, чтобы ответ не лепило в одну строчку. bulder.append(line).append("\n"); - перенос не надо было добавлять. В итоге оставил builder.append(line); и все заработало как надо)))